# Как задать цвет для кнопки с сохранением ripple-эффекта?

Tags: android, android-support-library

Использую в своем приложении (minSdk 9) кнопки `AppCompatButton`. Кнопки в моем приложении бывают разных цветов и могут становиться неактивными (`setEnabled(false)`).

Хочу сделать их плоскими и с ripple-анимацией, согласно материал-дизайну. Но не могу задать им цвет. Либо теряется ripple-эффект, либо они перестают становиться серыми в неактивном состоянии.

Как задать цвет кнопке, чтобы сохранился ripple-эффект, а в неактивном состоянии были серыми?

В данный момент есть это:

```
<style name="MyGreenButton"  parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
   <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#0f0</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
   android:theme="@style/MyGreenButton"/>
```

Кнопки меняют цвет, текст белый, но нет ripple-эффекта и в неактивном состоянии цвет остается зеленым.

Comment: ripple эффект только от лолипопа и выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось реализовать так. Проверял на версиях ОС от 2.3.3 до 6.0.1, работает (разумеется ripple-эффект только от 5).

**Разметка:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
  style="@style/MyButton"
  ...
  />
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
  <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_background_selector</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_selector</item>
</style>
```

**button_background_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#555555"/>
    <item android:color="#00ff00"/>
</selector>
```

**button_text_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#888888"/>
    <item android:color="#ffffff"/>
</selector>
```